# I need to join many query results in one result

Tags: mysql

I have many simple query to run in MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT deviceID
     , from_unixtime(timestamp) 
  FROM EventData 
 where accountID = '001' 
   and deviceID = 'FFF'   
 order 
    by timestamp desc 
 limit 1;
```

I'm doing this to get the max `timestamp` value of every `deviceID` in a really huge active table that's why I make many queries to get faster results.

I tried with "`deviceID IN(...)`" but it takes too long and I don't want to hung up the server.

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL` to get all of the results (or just `UNION` if you want unique results). However, take a look at the answer from Caius Jard - you should be able to just group the results. Multiple queries will often be slower than a single query. In this case, I would be very surprised if these two unioned queries ran faster than Caius' grouping query. If you are finding that queries are slow, you can use MySQL's `explain` functionality to find out why (generally it's because an index isn't being used).

Comment: I put just two lines, but I have about over 100. Please read my answer to Caius

Comment: A `union all` should do it for you then. Also - and I know I'm stating the obvious - when you reach the point that you can no longer execute basic queries (assuming you're utilizing your indexes correctly), it's probably time to start looking into new hardware, or moving to a cloud database.

Comment: The server is a dual physical Xeon E5-2670 with 32 threads and 128GB of RAM. Do you think that I need more powerfull server?

Comment: If I add UNION ALL i get an error code 1221. It don't like the ORDER BY

Comment: To keep your `order` and `limit` in place, just enclose your queries in parentheses. Eg `(select col from table1 order by col limit 1) union (select col from table2 order by col limit 1)`. See the [MySQL documentation on `UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) for more details.

Comment: As for your server, that sounds plenty powerful, but you're still unable to execute the queries you need. I'm not the right person to be giving you advice on your hardware requirements though. You may want to consider archiving data, or using a different engine (although innoDB sounds appropriate) - or even switching to an enterprise level RDBMS.  The [database administrators stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a more appropriate place for this tangent.

Comment: Yes, I need to learn a lot about database administration and design, I'm just a firmware, software and electronic engineer. I'm not an expert in database management. Unfortunately I have no time to read that's why i get here when something is out of my knowledge and learn step by step when I need to solve something.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using built in functions for summarising data?

```
SELECT 
  deviceID,
  from_unixtime(MAX(timestamp)) as timestamp
FROM 
  EventData 
where 
  accountID='001'
GROUP BY 
  deviceID
```

Comment: That account have over a thousand deviceID and I need the max timestamp of about one hundred. The table is a innoDB and is really huge(over 250GB) and active, so MAX function doesn't work, I already tried and get wrong results.

Comment: Max doesn't work as in MySQL refuses to run the query? Or it just takes too long? Is accountid/deviceid/timestamp triplet indexed? My query could then be answered entirely from the index. If there proves to be no good way to get data via a max query, you might want to look to use a trigger that maintains a separate table of single device id and timestamp; trigger updates the time stamp column if the row being inserted to the large table has a higher timestamp than the one in the small table. The small table can then be used for this query

Comment: MAX give me wrong results. I tried with only one ID that I know the right timestamp (15 minutes ago) and get me a timestamp from about 2 months ago. And yes, the three columns are primary key.

Comment: Never in my life have I known a database to get a max wrong. Can you reproduce that? (Take that 3 months ago row, and a latest one, into another table and ask again for the max.. is it repeatable? MySQL dev team would be very interested to know if so..)